# Python inheritance mro() quirk

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, method-resolution-order

Can anyone explain why the mro depth first traversal does this?

If my parent class inherits from two middle classes that both inherit from the same origin class, then the order of resolution follows the mro list. Seems fine...

```py
class Origin1:
    def hello(self):
        print("Hello from Origin1")


class Middle1(Origin1):
    def hello(self):
        super().hello()
        print("Hello from Middle1")


class Middle2(Origin1):
    def hello(self):
        super().hello()
        print("Hello from Middle2")


class Parent(Middle1, Middle2):
    def hello(self):
        super().hello()
        print("Hello from Parent")


p = Parent()
p.hello()

# Hello from Origin1
# Hello from Middle2
# Hello from Middle1
# Hello from Parent
#[
#<class '__main__.Parent'>, 
#<class '__main__.Middle1'>, 
#<class '__main__.Middle2'>, 
#<class '__main__.Origin1'>, <—-starts here
#<class 'object'>
#]
```

However, if my two middle classes have a different origin class, then only Middle1/Origin1 process `hello()` and the other two are ignored. Why would `Middle2.hello()` evaluate on the first example but not the second?

```py
class Origin1:
    def hello(self):
        print("Hello from Origin1")


class Origin2:
    def hello(self):
        print("Hello from Origin2")


class Middle1(Origin1):
    def hello(self):
        super().hello()
        print("Hello from Middle1")


class Middle2(Origin2):
    def hello(self):
        super().hello()
        print("Hello from Middle2")


class Parent(Middle1, Middle2):
    def hello(self):
        super().hello()
        print("Hello from Parent")


p = Parent()
p.hello()
print(Parent.mro())

# Hello from Origin1
# Hello from Middle1
# Hello from Parent
# [ 
#     < class '__main__.Parent' > , 
#     < class '__main__.Middle1' > , 
#     < class '__main__.Origin1' > , <——starts here 
#     < class '__main__.Middle2' > , <—-ignores this
#     < class '__main__.Origin2' > , <—-and this
#     < class 'object' > 
# ]
```

Comment: Because `Origin1` doesn't call `super`, so there's nowhere to go afterwards.

Comment: That's counterintuitive, since in the code, Origin1 is not inheriting from Middle2 but apparently calling super() just traverses the mro()?

Comment: `super()` just goes one step in the MRO. To traverse the entire hierarchy, the uppermost class needs to call `super()` to keep going along another branch.

Comment: Using `super` just calls the _next_ implementation in the chain. For multiple inheritance to work, you need to actually write classes that cooperate in it. Your implementation works its way up the MRO as far as it can go, but `Origin1` breaks the chain - no it doesn't inherit from `Middle2`, but we're working our way through `Parent`, which does.

Comment: Think of it this way: Python automatically calls one `__init__()`, and there are three classes containing a `super().__init__()` call.  Therefore, a maximum of four classes get initialized - but you have five of them.

Comment: @jasonharper There are no `__init__()` calls.

Comment: Thank you all, appreciate the explanation.